# React's Context API with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tavdvu?file=Booklist.tsx)

Its a simple React app using Typescript.

I'm trying to use Reacts Context api

I've created a context `ThemeContext` with simple theme styling values to use in other components.

I'm then trying to use this theme context to styled a list of books - `Booklist.tsx`

My problem is I can't get it to work at all and nothing displays

Sorry I know it's very vague but can anyone help and see where I'm going wrong.

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import BookList from './Booklist';
import ThemeContextProvider from './ThemeContext';

const App:React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeContextProvider>
        <BookList />
      </ThemeContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ThemeContext.tsx

```
import React, {createContext} from 'react'

export interface Props {}

export interface State {
    lightTheme: boolean
    light:{syntax: string, ui: string, bg: string}
    dark:{syntax: string, ui: string, bg: string}
    toggleTheme:boolean
}

const defaultState:State = {
    lightTheme: true,
    light:{syntax:'', ui:'', bg:''},
    dark:{syntax:'', ui:'', bg:''},
    toggleTheme:false
}

export const ThemeContext = createContext(defaultState)

class ThemeContextProvider extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: Props){
        super(props)

        this.state = { 
            lightTheme: true,
            light: {syntax: '#555', ui: '#ddd', bg: '#eee'},
            dark: {syntax: '#ddd', ui: '#333', bg: '#555'},
            toggleTheme: false
        }
    }

    render() { 
        return (  
            <ThemeContext.Provider value={{...this.state}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default ThemeContextProvider;
```

Booklist.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { ThemeContext } from './ThemeContext';

export interface Props {}

export interface State {
    lightTheme: boolean
    light:Darkness
    dark:Darkness
}

interface Darkness{
    syntax: string
    ui: string
    bg: string 
}

class BookList extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    render() { 
      return(
        <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {(state) => {
          const { lightTheme, light, dark} = this.state
          const theme = lightTheme ? light : dark
          return(
                  <div style={{color: theme.syntax, background: theme.bg}}>
                      <ul>
                          <li style={{background:theme.ui}}>Book One</li>
                          <li style={{background:theme.ui}}>Book Two</li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
          )
        }}</ThemeContext.Consumer>
      )
    }
}

export default BookList;
```

Comment: What errors are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missing
render

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
```

```
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[in your demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vdjdsj?file=index.tsx)

Comment: Should your demo work, I get `Error in /~/Booklist.tsx (29:51)
Cannot read property 'lightTheme' of null`

Comment: now it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vdjdsj?file=Booklist.tsx
remove ``this`` from 
          ``const { lightTheme, light, dark} = state``